# STRUCT CUSTOM JSON ARRAY?

Tags: json, array, swift, xcode, swift4

Mi JSON es este:

```
{
…
    "episodes": {
        "1": [
            {
                "id": 533072,
                "season": 1,
                "episode": 1,
                "nombre": "La hija del general",
                "firstaired": "2012-12-06",
                "const": 8
            },
            {
                "id": 533078,
                "season": 1,
                "episode": 2,
                "nombre": "Caballo de Troya",
                "firstaired": "2012-12-06",
                "const": 8
            },
            {
                "id": 533073,
                "season": 1,
                "episode": 3,
                "nombre": "Cosecha",
                "firstaired": "2012-12-06",
                "const": 8
            },
…
}
```

Mi pregunta es, como creo la estructura del JSON en Swift 4?
He intentado esto:

```
 struct detailInfo: Decodable{
      let seasons: [seasons]?
      let episodes: episodes

}
 struct seasons: Decodable{
      let id: Int
      let season: Int
}
 struct episodes: Decodable{
 ???
}
```

No sé como continuar el JSON a partir de aquí...

Gracias!!

Comment: Please translate your question, this is  ES.stackoverflow.com....

Comment: Lo siento, no me acordé que estaba en stackoverflow español, traducido está!

Comment: simplemente tienes los parámetros necesarios en el json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo lo haría de la siguiente manera, tal vez tu necesitas estructurar cada parámetro como lo estas implementando pero yo lo simplificaría en una sola estructura.... en caso que solo necesites el "episode" solo agrega los parámetros que vas a utilizar en ese struct de "episodes" por cierto, no se de que manera tienes tu request para sacar los datos del json... pero igual si ya los estas recibiendo con un getRequest solamente jalalos a la estructura.

```
    struct Episodes {
        id: Int
        season: Int
        episode: Int
        nombre: String
        firstaired: Date
        const: Int
        }
```

después para sacarlo del json crea un array vacío en el view controller donde lo vas a necesitar ...

```
         var episodes = [Episodes]()
```

y cuando estes en el request para obtener los datos del json estos normalmente siempre vienen con un completion, pero no se como lo tengas, yo te pongo por ejemplo ...

```
 func getJsonObject() {
    requestJson { [weak self] (json, error) {  <-
         // no olvides sacar el error con un guard o un if let....
    guard let jsonValue = json.value(forkey: "episodes") as NSDictionary,
    let dictionaryValue = jsonValue.value(forkey: "1" as? [NSDictionary]  else { return }
    for (index, value) in dictionaryValue.enumarate() {
            let id = value.value(forkey: "id") as? Int
            let season = value.value(forkey: "season") as? Int
       }
```

y asi en cada uno, y para añadirlos al array que creaste pues simplemente le das el set dentro del for....

```
       let addEpisode = Episodes(id: id, season: season, nombre... y cada uno de los parametros
```

después para añadirlos al array simplemente le das un append....

```
        episodes.append(addEpisode)
```

va ir recorriendo los elementos y se añadirán en el array... esto es de manera nativa.. si usas alamofire o swiftyJSON es mucho mas simple.. 
otra cosa se recomienda poner un removeAll de la variable array antes del ciclo ( me imagino que usaras un collection view o un TableView) esto evitara que se dupliquen los elementos...

```
     episodes.removeAll()
     for (index, value) in. etc etc
```

no se si es mas o menos lo que estas buscando.. pero igual inténtalo, saludos y espero pueda servirte de ayuda